# Visual Studio - Compilation error

Tags: c, embedded, preprocessor-directive

I'm using `Visual Studio 2005` and getting trained in building `WinCE 6.0` OS Image. I'm in the pin mux setup part. I have set a macro `BSP_HC1`, so the coding with that macro alone should work. A part of the coding is,

```
#define GPMC_PADS \
#ifdef BSP_HC1
    PAD_ENTRY(GPMC_A6   ,INPUT_DISABLED | MUXMODE(SAFE_MODE))   \
    PAD_ENTRY(GPMC_nCS2 ,INPUT_DISABLED | MUXMODE(0))   
#else
    PAD_ENTRY(GPMC_A1       ,INPUT_DISABLED | MUXMODE(0))     \
    PAD_ENTRY(GPMC_A2       ,INPUT_DISABLED | MUXMODE(0))     \
    PAD_ENTRY(GPMC_A3       ,INPUT_DISABLED | MUXMODE(0))
#endif
```

The IntelliSense was correctly showing the else part as an inactive code. But, while I select Build, I was getting error as "`error: C2449 found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)`".

So, I added backslashes at the end of `#ifdef, #else and #endif`.

```
#define GPMC_PADS \
#ifdef BSP_HC1  \
    PAD_ENTRY(GPMC_A6   ,INPUT_DISABLED | MUXMODE(SAFE_MODE))   \
    PAD_ENTRY(GPMC_nCS2 ,INPUT_DISABLED | MUXMODE(0))   \
#else   \
    PAD_ENTRY(GPMC_A1       ,INPUT_DISABLED | MUXMODE(0))     \
    PAD_ENTRY(GPMC_A2       ,INPUT_DISABLED | MUXMODE(0))     \
    PAD_ENTRY(GPMC_A3       ,INPUT_DISABLED | MUXMODE(0))     \
#endif
```

There were no errors while building. But, I wonder whether I have done the right thing and my coding will do the intended purpose, because I have done it blindly. I thought that the `#ifdef` and other related pre-processor directives need not be included in the macro definition `GPMC_PADS` and the compiler would treat it separately. Kindly explain me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: You might like to take a look at the pre-processor's output to see what it did to your construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use pre-processor directives within `#define`s.

Do it this way:

```
#ifdef BSP_HC1
#define GPMC_PADS \
  PAD_ENTRY(GPMC_A6   ,INPUT_DISABLED | MUXMODE(SAFE_MODE))   \
  PAD_ENTRY(GPMC_nCS2 ,INPUT_DISABLED | MUXMODE(0))   
#else
#define GPMC_PADS \
  PAD_ENTRY(GPMC_A1       ,INPUT_DISABLED | MUXMODE(0))     \
  PAD_ENTRY(GPMC_A2       ,INPUT_DISABLED | MUXMODE(0))     \
  PAD_ENTRY(GPMC_A3       ,INPUT_DISABLED | MUXMODE(0))
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The file got compiled successfully. Could you please tell me, in what else should we not use pre-processor directives?

Comment: Thanks. What about #ifdef within a switch 'case'?